# Simple nodeJS example not working with socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Have been struggling all day trying to make this simple example work using socket.io. I've tried initially on Windows 7 with Cygwin. Have since also tried on OS X, with the same result.

When running the script, it shows this...

```
2 May 20:57:47 - socket.io ready - accepting connections
```

But visiting the index.html page doesnt show a client has even connected.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="socket.io.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var socket = new io.Socket('localhost',{'port':8090});

    socket.connect();

    socket.on('connect', function(){
        console.log('connected');
        socket.send('hi!'); 
    });

    socket.on('message', function(data){ 
        console.log('message recived: ' + data);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('disconected');
    });
</script> 
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

server.js

```
var http = require('http'), io = require('socket.io'),

server = http.createServer(function(req, res){ 
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); 
    res.end('<h1>Hello world</h1>'); 
});
server.listen(8090);

var socket = io.listen(server); 
socket.on('connection', function(client){ 
    console.log('client connected');

    client.on('message', function(){ 
        console.log('message arrive');
        client.send('some message');
    });

    client.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('connection closed');
    });
});
```

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong? No console messages whatsoever are being displayed. Notably, when i use Firebug to look at the index.html page, no scripts are being embedded, which is odd..Not sure what could be causing that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not serving up socket.io.js (or the flash file).

I'd recomend using the CDN:

`<script src="http://cdn.socket.io/stable/socket.io.js"></script>`

or alternatively use [express](http://expressjs.com/) to serve the socket.io.js file.

edit:

err actually looking closer you're also not serving up index.html
again express could work but for the simple example:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var index = fs.readFileSync('index.html');
//note the readFileSync is done only in the first tic
.
.
.
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); 
res.end(index);
```

Comment: There are actually some problems using the CDN version..  for me websockets didn't work..    I'd suggest sticking to the local version

Comment: Ah, that was it! I initally was using express, but went back to http to isolate the issue. I've gone back to express and started using the app.configure('development') function. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9):

You're not loading the socket.io library properly in your index.html file.  Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8090/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Comment: +1, correct and better way than getting script from remote host.

Answer (score 1):

Use this on the client side as the path !

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, and comment the following line:

```
// server.listen(8090);
```